# Check history session run by DB Link oracle

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have created a database link from `DB1` to `table2` in `DB2`

```sql
Create database link mylink
Connect to user identified by passwd
Using DB2
```

Then in `DB1` I run query:

```sql
Select * from table2@mylink
```

In DB2, can I check the sql text above and find out what machine, OS user running this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. But be aware that Oracle translates your SQL over a remote link and it won't be exactly the same, but still basically recognizable. One thing you will notice is all identifiers are in all-caps and surrounded by double-quotes. The second thing is that the `osuser` will be `oracle` (assuming that default software owner is used for the source database), and the `machine` will be the host of the source database. It will have no identifying information tying you directly to your client session, because your oracle-owned *shadow process* is what is establishing the connection to the remote. In other words the `v$process.spid` value of your local session will be the `v$session.process` of the remote session.

If you know your local session, you can find it that way:

local:

`select spid from gv$process where (inst_id,addr) in (select inst_id,paddr from gv$session where sid = ? and session# = ? and inst_id = ?)`

remote:

`select * from gv$session where process = {spid from above} and machine = {source db host}`

Otherwise, you can try searching the shared pool for the SQL. In your target database, query `gv$sqlarea` filtering on the table name, in all caps and surrounded by double-quotes:

`select * from gv$sqlarea where sql_fulltext like '%"TABLE2"%'` and see if you can locate it that way. If it's currently running you can join on `sql_id` to `gv$session` to get the session information. If it ran in the recent past, you may be able to find it in `gv$active_session_history`.